# How to run a model stored as a .Rda file?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, classification, r

I am using an already written R code which has a line of code as shown below

```
model_predictors <- buildModel(flag, data, outcomeName, folder)
model<-model_predictors$model
predictorsNames<-model_predictors$predictorsNames
auc <- model_predictors$auc
save(model, file=paste(folder,studyName,'_model_', flag$model[1], '_', outcomeName,".Rda",sep=''))
```

As you can see in the last line of code, the (training) model is saved in `folder` in a `.Rda` file format with a naming convention `_model_`. Now, I have to use this model to test/evaluate on unseen dataset.

So now my question, I see a `.Rda` file in my folder path and I can load the `.Rda` file in Rstudio but how do I make inference from this model? I am new to R and can anyone help me with this please?

Can someone help me understand how to run this model please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you come from Python. R is quite different as it does not require to save to external files your model, you just need to have it in your workspace. Once you have a model object, you just have to use the predict function and specify the unseen dataset. Here's an example of a tree model:

```
model<-tree(Y~X1+X2, data=dataset) #estimate of the tree model
predictions<-predict(model, newdata=unseen_dataset) #prediction on new data
```

Be sure variable names between datasets correspond.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Upvoted and marked